# In Angular, do i use a parent component's methods in child or use a service instead?

Tags: angular, components, parent-child

I have an Angular shared (child) component that displays a card with data from a server. There are two other components that will be using this child component in an ngFor loop to display multiple cards. The child component will need the server data but it also has functions in the html template. Where is an appropriate place to put the logic for those functions and also the API GET methods for the data?

Do i put the logic in each parent component that will use the shared component - this would be duplicating the code? Or create a service that includes the API data and also the functions the child component uses, then feed that service into the child component?

**UPDATE**: I got it working by using the suggested @Input() to get data from the parent into the child and @Output() to send the child's template functions (which reside in the parent component) out to the parent to be executed.

**NEW PROBLEM**: A problem now arised where a function in the parent also returns a value. So basically, I'm using @Output() to send the function out from the child and then processing the value in the parent then sending it back to the child. How do i get this value to show in the child component in the correct order? I put the value into a global variable in the parent and use @Input() in the child to get the variable but it is returning wrong order of values..

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you do not want to be retrieving any data from a server in "presentation" components, which is what I would say your card component is. In order to give yourself the most flexibility, I would favour retrieving data in the parent components using a shared service and passing it into the "child" component via [inputs](https://angular.io/api/core/Input). This way, your child component can receive its data in any way the parent component sees fit. Sometimes you might not want to retrieve it from the server, you might, for example, cache the data in local storage. By passing the data through an input property, you give your component the most reusability, as its only job is to present the data it is given.

If your "presentation" (card) components are able to modify the data, I would suggest not updating the data directly in the child component, but emitting the new data using [outputs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs), and then modifying the source of your data in the parent component. Modifying it in the parent component will then update the child component through the above input properties. If you modify the data directly in the child component, you risk your data getting out of sync, as your parent will have one value and your child will have another.

Comment: Before i started creating the child component, the parent component had all the html that included functions that processed server data from it's typescript class logic. Now that i decided to create a new shared component to display the html, i still have all those functions inside the html template in the shared component, but all the functions' logic still in the parent's typescript. How do i get those functions to work when they reside in the parent? Would this be a case for those outputs?

Comment: I think at this point you'll need to show me some code before I can assist further.